# Get list in dictionary with string interpolation

Tags: python, string, dictionary, string-interpolation

I'm trying to get a value from a dictionary with string interpolation.

The dictionary has some digits, and a list of digits:

```
d = { "year" : 2010, \
"scenario" : 2, \
"region" : 5, \
"break_points" : [1,2,3,4,5] }
```

Is it possible to reference the list in a string interpolation, or do I need to identify unique keys for each?

Here's what I've tried:

```
str = "Year = %(year)d, \
Scenario = %(scenario)d, \
Region = %(region)d, \
Break One = %(break_points.0)d..." % d
```

I've also tried `%(break_points[0])d`, and `%(break_points{'0'})d`

Is this possible to do, or do I need to give them keys and save them as integers in the dictionary?

Comment: unrelated but lose the backslashes

Comment: Thought it would be more readable on StackOverflow.  It's not like that in the code.

Comment: @bozdoz Python allows multiline string literals using `"""`.

Comment: Better practice? @Zoidberg

Comment: Much better than backslashes, yes.

Comment: The backslashes in the dict literal are especially useless.

Comment: Sorry guys.  I panicked. :)

Comment: The backslashes in the string literal serve a purpose — they remove the newlines that will be present if `"""` is used. The alternative here is to put the strings in parentheses and use the magic autoconcatenation. I can't demonstrate it cleanly in a comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with new-style formatting:

```
print "{0[break_points][0]:d}".format(d)
```

or

```
print "{break_points[0]:d}".format(**d)
```

[str.format documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

> The string on which this method is called can contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by braces `{}`. Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument.

[Format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

> The field_name itself begins with an `arg_name` that is either a number or a keyword. If it’s a number, it refers to a positional argument, and if it’s a keyword, it refers to a named keyword argument.
>
> ...
>
> The arg_name can be followed by any number of index or attribute expressions. An expression of the form `'.name'` selects the named attribute using `getattr()`, while an expression of the form `'[index]'` does an index lookup using `__getitem__()`.

Comment: Awesome.  What's going on in both?

Comment: First one gets the whole dict as the first (index `0`) field and indexes it twice (like `field0['break_points'][0]`). Second gets the dict items as individual named fields, i.e. as `.format(break_points=[1,2,3,4,5], region=5, ...)`. The first element of the `break_points` field is then  taken.

Comment: The `:d` is the same "decimal integer" presentation as in old-printf-style `%d`.

Comment: Ah.  That's what was confusing me. :)  I was thinking it was referencing the dictionary.  Thanks!